# Post traverse recursion in VBA to calculate a consolidated status

Tags: vba, post, recursion, traversal, consolidation

[image]

My apologies as I'm new to VBA. I'm looking for a post-traverse example to resolve the below problem. I'd like to recursively traverse the tree in column A to calculate a consolidated status. As in my example table below "Real Proj 1" has status A (=Amber). "Real Proj 2 and 3 have both status G (Green). Because one of the sub projects of program B contains Amber, it's calculated status should be Amber (see column C). Or the consolidated status of "Simplification" on row 2 is Amber as all its children ("Real Proj A", Program B and C) contain at least one status of Amber.

The values in column A contain indentations, i.e.  "Program A" on row 3 has indentation level = 1, "Real Proj 2" on row 6 has indentation level = 3.
Any help on how to implement this in VBA with recursion would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Chris

Here is my solution. Hope this helps somebody else too.
Best,
Chris

```
Sub TestStatus()
    Call PopulateStatus(2)
End Sub

Sub PopulateStatus(rowIndex As Integer)
    Dim level As Integer
    Dim children() As Integer
    Dim child As Integer
    Dim existingStatus As String
    Dim calculatedStatus As String
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim aggregatedRow As Integer


    If (hasChildren(rowIndex)) Then
        aggregatedRow = rowIndex
        children = getChildren(rowIndex)

        ' Do something with the children
        For counter = LBound(children) To UBound(children)
            child = children(counter)
            Call PopulateStatus(child)
        Next counter

        'Write aggregated status of all children to column B
        calculatedStatus = getStatus(children)
        Cells(aggregatedRow, 2).Value = calculatedStatus
    Else
        existingStatus = Cells(rowIndex, 2).Value
        ' Check if we are last in children
        If (Cells(rowIndex, 1).IndentLevel > Cells(rowIndex + 1, 1).IndentLevel) Then
            'Cells(aggregatedRow, 2).Value = calculatedStatus
        End If

    End If

End Sub



Function getStatus(ByRef myArray() As Integer) As String
    Dim resultStatus As String
    Dim currentStatus As String
    Dim counter As Integer
    resultStatus = "G"

    For counter = 0 To UBound(myArray)
        currentStatus = Cells(myArray(counter), 2).Value

        If currentStatus = "R" Or resultStatus = "R" Then
            calculateStatus = "R"
            Exit Function
        End If

        If currentStatus = "A" Then
            resultStatus = "A"
        End If

        If currentStatus = "G" And resultStatus = "A" Then
            resultStatus = "A"
        End If
    Next
    getStatus = resultStatus

End Function



Function getChildren(rowIndex As Integer) As Variant
    Dim children() As Integer
    Dim myIndLevel As Integer
    Dim newIndLevel As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    myIndLevel = Cells(rowIndex, 1).IndentLevel
    count = 0
    For counter = rowIndex + 1 To 14
        newIndLevel = Cells(counter, 1).IndentLevel
        If (newIndLevel = myIndLevel + 1 And newIndLevel <> myIndLevel) Then
            ReDim Preserve children(count) As Integer
            children(count) = counter
            rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next
    getChildren = children
End Function



Function hasChildren(myRow As Integer)
    Dim indLevel As Integer
    Dim newLevel As Integer
    indLevel = Cells(myRow, 1).IndentLevel
    newLevel = Cells(myRow + 1, 1).IndentLevel

    If newLevel > indLevel Then
        hasChildren = True
        Exit Function
    End If
    hasChildren = False
End Function
```

Comment: How do you indicate which projects are "sub-projects" of a project - is it literally with a "Real Proj xxx" string? It is important to make this clear, or a solution is impossible to code. Also - you don't want to label `Program A` as `green`? Is that because it has no sub-projects? Please expand your question... it will result in better answers.

Comment: Are you using spaces for indentation or something else? I noticed that you didn't update the image in your question to reflect "Green on row 3 should be in column C"

Comment: I use CTRL+ALT+TAB = increase indent in a cell.

Comment: Small correction: Status of row 3 is also an existing status.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I just edited my question. I use indention levels in column A. Any row which does not have following rows with a higher indention level are considered leafs. So leafs are row 5 to 7 and 9 to 10 and row 3.

Comment: Hint:Excel Developer Reference/
Range.IndentLevel Property: 
Returns or sets a Variant value that represents the indent level for the cell or range. Can be an integer from 0 to 15.

Comment: Posted my solution above.